# php regex replace clear span code

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to build a PHP preg replace string when processing poorly written html, such that if I am given:

```html
<span class='chr'>G#</span>         <span class='chr'>Cm</span><br>
       Yenilmedi<br>
<span class='chr'>A#</span><span class='chr'>G#</span>    <span class='chr'>Cm</span><br>
Açık seçik sizle oynamadı
```

I want to delete span codes and between

Sample:

```html
Yenilmedi <br>
Açık seçik sizle oynamadı
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(<span.*\/span>)/u', '', $str);
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Toto Yes, it works fine. Of course regex isn't good to work with XML/HTML at all.

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]